# How to use a thread inside a class constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is there any possible way to use threads inside a class like this:

```
Class Logger // singleton class
{
//.... here is implemented thread logic 
{

void main()
{
   Logger& log = Logger::getInstance();
   log.writeMessage(); // this should execute in another thread
                       // also, all the other func from Logger class
                       // should execute in that second thread

   // ... some code -> executes in main thread

   log.deleteInstance(); // join threads

}
```

I need to mention that I'm new to threading. I just need an idea so I can start thinking how it works.

Comment: Yes, you can do it. What form would an answer to this take without actually writing the code? What does an "idea" look like? It's probably not a trivial project.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but are you sure it's necessary?  Threading will add a *lot* of complexity to your program.

Comment: Basically, you need some kind of queue that the main thread can use to send messages to the logging thread.

Comment: @Barmar by an ideea i mean something like: should i start the thread in the constructor and stop the thread at the disctruction of the class? or should i start and end the thread in every function that i write? I really dont know how to start

Comment: @0x5453 well i want to try to see how this should work, right now a dont really care about complexity. I want to learn to do a thing like that

Comment: Instead of the singleton pattern where you have to call `getInstance()` explicitly, you can just have a global variable of `class Logger`. See [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/DzS-VJ).

Comment: While technical possible, I think that in practice it rarely a good idea to start a thread in a constructor. For example, you could have problem if an exception is thrown after you start the thread but before the constructor is complete. Also, it might be easier to configure the class object before you start the thread by calling some member function and then call a start method when you are ready.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're describing is a worker thread that will run in the background. I wouldn't start a new thread every time you call `WriteMessage()` as thread creation is fairly expensive, and starting and stopping your thread can actually slow down your program. Instead you can start a thread in the constructor of the class and let it monitor a queue. Other clients of your `Logger` class can use the `WriteMessage()` function to push something onto the queue. The logger will detect some job has arrived and process it. At the end when you're finished call a `Stop()` function to stop the thread.

To do all this your thread has to execute a function that runs a loop. You can use a [condition variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) to wait on a condition, i.e. a job request or stop command. The advantage of a condition variable is that all the thread synchronization is done for you. You just have to specify the condition as a predicate. Putting something on the queue would have to be an atomic operation. You can use a [std::lock_guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) for that.

You can call other functions in `Logger` from the main thread while the worker thread sits in the background doing its job. That's not a problem.

Here's an implementation of this `Logger` class:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

class Logger // singleton class
{
public:
    Logger() : mThread{}, mCV{}, mMutex{}, mQueue{}, mStop{ false }
    {
        mThread = std::thread(&Logger::Run, this); //create thread and execute Run()
    }

    ~Logger()
    {
        //Join thread
        if (mThread.joinable())
        {
            mThread.join();
        }
    }

    static Logger& getInstance() {
        static Logger logger;
        return logger;
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        {
            //Set the stop flag
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mMutex);
            mStop = true;
        }
        mCV.notify_one();
    }

    void WriteMessage(const std::string& msg)
    {
        {
            //Push a request on the queue
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mMutex);
            mQueue.push(msg);
        }
        mCV.notify_one();
    }

private:
    void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //Wait until some request comes or stop flag is set
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mMutex);
            mCV.wait(lock, [&]() { return mStop || !mQueue.empty(); });

            //Stop if needed
            if (mStop)
            {
                break;
            }

            //Pop the job off the front of the queue
            std::string msg = std::move(mQueue.front());
            mQueue.pop();
            //Unlock the mutex
            lock.unlock();

            std::cout << msg << std::endl;
        }
    }

private:
    std::thread mThread;
    std::condition_variable mCV;
    std::mutex mMutex;
    std::queue<std::string> mQueue;
    bool mStop;
};
```

Working version here: https://ideone.com/wYIaMY

Answer (score 0):

You can execute code in a second thread with a lambda expression like so:

```cpp
void main()
{
    Logger& log = Logger::getInstance();
    std::thread thread([] () {
        Logger& log = Logger::getInstance();
        log.writeMessage(); // second thread
    });
    log.writeMessage(); // main thread

    thread.join(); // wait for second thread to finish
    log.deleteInstance();
}
```

What you can't (easily) do is call `writeMessage()` in the main thread and expect it to do its work in the second. Calls don't "jump across threads"; you call a function, it executes in the ongoing thread, it returns, and you continue on in the ongoing thread.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is nothing preventing you from using threads in the member functions of a class. However, there are many ways to approach this problem.

You could create a `std::thread` in the constructor of `class Logger`, and then have member functions which are called in the main thread somehow signal the secondary thread to do some work on its behalf. That will typically involve a message queue. It's not too hard to implement, but also not trivial.

A simpler approach would be to just use [`std::async()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) to run a function asynchronously. You can either have `writeMessage()` itself call `std::async()`, but then the question is how it will clean up after itself. The simplest is to just call `std::async()` from the main thread:

```
void main() {
    Logger &log = Logger::getInstance();
    {
        auto future = std::async(std::launch::async, [&log]{log.writeMessage});
        // ... some code -> executes in main thread
    } // exiting this scope waits for the async call to finish
    log.deleteInstance(); 
}
```